# simple select statement and echo the selected value

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

I just want a simple code of the **jsp** and the **servlet** which has a **drop down** menu and based on the choice that user selects i want it to echo some response on the same page say the selected choice only

I found link that redirect to different pages based on the selection but i want the data to be populated on the same page below the select menu.

Could'nt find anything.. Help is highly appreciated.. pls give the code for the jsp file and the servlet.. PLS

This is the jsp file
`<form action="scheduleMeet" method="post">

        <select name="Dept">
            <option value="Personalization">Personalization</option>
            <option value="WebDevelopment">WebDevelopment</option>
            <option value="MobileApp">MobileApp</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>`

and the servlet is

`    package controller;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import service.scheduleMeetService;


//@WebServlet("/scheduleMeet")
public class meetServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
 HttpServletResponse    response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String deptName = request.getParameter("Dept");

}
```

}
`

Now i dont know.. what to do next how to display some text on the same page lets say print the deptName only

Comment: Could your post code, what you have done so far?

Comment: @atishshimpi Can u pls help i am really stuck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your servlet redirect to your page where from request came, then pass the required message in as parameter to your jsp and then display it where you want.
e.g. In your servlet pass `nemeForEhco` to jsp

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/pages
/userHome.jsp?nameForEcho=Pass selected name");
```

In JSP, take your name

```
<% String nemeForEhco = request.getParameter("nameForEcho"); %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and also for being patient enough to answer such silly question.  I am a total newbie to Web Development so didn't know how to do it.